# Applying a CSS class to a javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I have a popup window working with the following code, but I need to amend it to apply a CSS class to either the HTML tag or the Body tag, so I can style the popup window differently than the normal site.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
/****************************************************
     Author: Eric King
     Url: http://redrival.com/eak/index.shtml
     This script is free to use as long as this info is left in
     Featured on Dynamic Drive script library (http://www.dynamicdrive.com)
****************************************************/
var win=null;
function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll,pos){
if(pos=="random"){LeftPosition=(screen.width)?Math.floor(Math.random()*(screen.width-w)):100;TopPosition=(screen.height)?Math.floor(Math.random()*((screen.height-h)-75)):100;}
if(pos=="center"){LeftPosition=(screen.width)?(screen.width-w)/2:100;TopPosition=(screen.height)?(screen.height-h)/2:100;}
else if((pos!="center" && pos!="random") || pos==null){LeftPosition=0;TopPosition=20}
settings='width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no';
win=window.open(mypage,myname,settings);
}
// -->
</script>
```

I tried to add a line right after the win=window.open line that looked like this:

```
win.document.getElementById('body').className += " popup";
```

Unfortunately it didn't work. Any ideas on how I can make it so if a window is popped up using this javascript function it'll apply a CSS class to the window?

The HTML call to the function was with this code, if it matters.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'broadcastplayer','600','200','no','center');return false" onfocus="this.blur()">Play in pop up</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
```

Alternatively I've tried using this jquery version of a popup window (http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html), but haven't figured out how to do it this way either. Thank you so much for your help, this has been killing me all day!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see u are trying to reach object with `id='body'`. 
However i think that your markup looks like
`<body> ... </body>`. If that's true then You can't use JS function getElementById because You have no ID on body element :)

The solution would be `<body id='body'> ... </body>`

Also You can use different JS function to select the body.
`var body = document.getElementsByTagName( "body" );`

Answer (score 0):

**win.document.getElementById('body')**

will look for DOM element which matches the provided ID and in this case there is no element whose ID is body.

try to replace this with **win.document.getElementsByTagName('body')**. this should give you the body tag then you can apply the CSS class to it.

Since you will only have one body in your document you can directly assign the class to body tag in popup HTML itself.

Comment: Ok I'm using this code, but it still isn't applying a new css class to the body element.

Comment: win.document.getElementsByTagName('body').className += " popup";

Comment: try out this win.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className +=' popup' ;  even you can check what all classes your body tag has in firebug console by win.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className. This should show you the class popup along with others if you have one.